# Is $\frac{\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{2}}{b-2}$ the same as $\frac{\frac{2-b}{2b}}{b-2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Have I subtracted 2 fractions correctly?

$\frac{\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{2}}{b-2}$

Starting with the numerator which is a difference of fractions, the least common denominator is 2b? So:

$\frac{2(1)}{2b}-\frac{b(1)}{2b}$ = $\frac{2}{2b}-\frac{b}{2b}$ = $\frac{2-b}{2b}$

So my newly simplified expression is:

$\frac{\frac{2-b}{2b}}{b-2}$

My question - is this correct? If yes, great - now how would I go about simplifying further by taking the denominator $b-2$ into account? If no, where did I go wrong?

Comment: b-2 = -1(2-b)  XXX

Comment: As long as $b\ne2$

Comment: Looks fine to me. When you have a fraction rather than dividing you can think of it as multiplying the inverse. This means you're looking at $\frac{2-b}{2b} \frac{1}{b-2}$. If you factor a negative one out from one of the term you'll end up with a $2-b$ term in the numerator and denominator so they'll cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$Yes, it is right. And now:$$\frac{\frac{2-b}{2b}}{b-2}=-\frac{\frac{\cancel{b-2}}{2b}}{\cancel{b-2}}=-\frac1{2b}.$$

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. I'm intrigued. What rule allowed you to go from the first to the second part, where you negative the equation and cross out the numerator's numerator and the denominator? I do not follow this part?

Comment: I used the fact that$$\frac{-a}b=-\frac ab.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, since $$\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{2b}-\frac{b}{2b}=\frac{2-b}{2b}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same, in fact the first fraction can be rewritten as $\frac{-(b-2)}{2b}\cdot \frac{1}{b-2}=-\frac{1}{2b}$. The second, instead: $\frac{-(b-2)}{2b}\cdot \frac{1}{2b}=-\frac{1}{2b}$.